# Sorting a list from max to min by of index number in LISP?

Tags: sorting, indexing, lisp, elisp, common-lisp

I am trying to write a function that takes a list, sorts it from high to low and then gives the original positions of the elements in the list ordered from high to low. Also, I would like there to be no repeats in the returned list.

So..

```
(LargestNumberIndex '( 1 23 101 5 6 5 )
```

should return

```
(2 1 4 3 5 0)
```

not

```
(2 1 4 3 3 0)
```

At the moment my function looks like this:

```
    (defun LargestNumberIndex (listofnums Indexes) 
  ;; make a copy of the list to sort
  (setf listcopy (copy-list listofnums))
  ;; sort list from high to low
  (setf sortlist (sort listcopy #'>))
  ;; compare the elements from both lists to determine the
  ;; position     
  (loop for i from 0 below Indexes collect
       (position (nth i sortlist) listofnums :test #'equal))

  ))
```

I cant figure out what to add to get it to work. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

#### Remarks

- Don't use SETF or SETQ for local variables (use LET)
- Do indent and format your code
- Use dashes in names, don't use CamelCase
- LOOP can iterate over lists: don't use NTH as you did

#### Decorate, sort, undecorate

(also known as [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform))

```
(defun largest-number-index (list)
  (mapcar #'second
          (stable-sort
            (loop
              for index from 0
              for element in list
              collect (list element index))
            #'>
            :key #'first)))

(largest-number-index '(1 23 101 5 6 5))
=> (2 1 4 3 5 0)
```

Comment: I would expect no duplicates in the result, since you explicitly track the original index. You would also need to use `stable-sort` to guarantee that you get `(2 1 4 3 5 0)` instead of `(2 1 4 5 3 0)`. Other than that, yes, the Schwartzian Transform is exactly the thing to use.